# PHP - Is there a way to verify all values in an array

Tags: php

Using PHP..

Here is what I have.. I'm gonna explain the whole thing and maybe someone can help me with the logic and maybe point me in the right direction.

I have a mail system I am working on. In the cc part, I am allowing the user to seperate the values by a semicolon, like so: 1;2;3;4...

When these values are passed to my function, I am using explode to get them into an array. What I want to do is some checking first. I want to firstly make certain that the format is correct and that every value is correctly seperated. If not, I should show an error. Once this is done, I want to make certain that every number is actually valid. I can query the database, put the reslts into an array and was thinking to use the in_array() function to verify this but I'm not certain that it will work. Can someone please help me out with the best way to handle this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

What is the best way to detect a bogus value in the CSV list of values?

Comment: Are the values just numbers? Can you give the most complex example of values that you'll have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to verify that each number was correct seperated, you want to check that there is no whitespace in the answer. So something like this should work:

```
$text = trim($id);
if(strpos(" ", $id) !== false)
{
    //error
}
```

Next, to check for the values, it is very simple

```
if(!in_array($id, $database_ids))
{
    // error
}
```

Finally, if you are only using numeric values, check that the id is numeric

```
if(!is_numeric($id))
{
    //error
}
```

To combine, wrap it into an array

```
foreach($exploded_array as $key => $id)
{
    $id = trim(id);
    if(!is_numeric($id))
    {
        //error
    }
    if(strpos(" ", $id) !== false)
    {
        //error
    } 
    if(!in_array($id, $database_ids))
    {
        // error
    }
}
```

I hope the code was pretty self explanatory where it got the variables, but if you need me to explain more, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hey Chacka, thanks. You actually helped me the other day; I remember you. Thanks, you nailed it.

Comment: Updated for the Numeric Values too. No problem. I keep most of my answers in a personal wiki anyways, so this will help me in future programs.

Comment: Chacha, just curious, what is the strpos function for? Thanks again.

Comment: it returns the position of a substring within a string, or false it it doesn't exist. Here it checks whether there is a space in $id or not. see http://php.net/strpos

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
   //do checking here
}
```

Comment: Kitson, I can loop through the values just fine but I need help with the logic.

Comment: ... and the best practice on what I'm doing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[array_filter](https://www.php.net/array_filter) could be an option.

Comment: Hey whichdan, thanks for the link, I never used that function before but it certainly can be useful. Thanks for sharing. :)

Answer (score 0):

As whichdan suggested, here is an implementation that relies on `array_filter()`:

```
<?php
function checkValue($value)
{
    $id = trim(id);
    if(!is_numeric($id))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(strpos(" ", $id) !== false)
    {
        return false;
    } 
    if(!in_array($id, $database_ids))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$values = '1;2;3;4';
$values_extracted = explode(';', $values);

if(count($values) == count(array_filter($values_extracted), 'checkValue'))
{
   // Input was successfully validated
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi phidah, I already implemented the changes with the exception of the strpos function. What is that for? BTW: Thanks for the array_filter code.